# Javascript "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" on 1 length item

Tags: javascript

I cannot read the `title` attribute from the `received` variable, but as you see the collection is not undefined, and the `title` attribute also not undefined.
The error saying its undefined.

```
var received = document.getElementsByClassName("_2her");
if (received[0].title == "Delivered") {
    chColorsForDelivered();
}
```

[image: as you see not undefined]
[image: its not undefined]

Comment: Not necessarily at the time of your `if()` statement execution. The little blue _i_ indicates that this was async.

Comment: Looks like your getting the live aspect of `console.log` confusing you.  Can you see this bit, `HTMLCollection[]`, basically at the point you console logged, the collection was empty, but at the point you expanded the collection is would be available.  LIke @RandyCasburn has mentioned above, this is most likely an async issue.

Comment: How is this element added to DOM? Do you control it?

Comment: Actually I am using messenger.com HTML codes and trying to manipulate them on certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your script started before DOM ready, If you are using html5, then use async with you script.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check that first element (and make sure it's there after the page loads), I usually use this method:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var received = document.getElementsByClassName("_2her")[0];
    if (received.title == "Delivered") {
        chColorsForDelivered();
    }
}
```

You could also use `querySelector` to get the first occurrence of the class, which might be more suited to your needs:

```
var received = document.querySelector("_2her");
if (received.title == "Delivered") {
    chColorsForDelivered();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var active;
var bg;
var received;
var rightDelivered;
var colorchint;

window.onload = function() {
    main();
}

//=================== FUNCTIONS ===================

async function main() {
    active = await document.getElementsByClassName("_2v6o");
    bg = document.getElementsByClassName("_673w");
    received = await document.getElementsByClassName("_2her");
    rightDelivered = document.getElementsByClassName("_2jnt");
    colorchint;

    bg[0].onmouseover = function() {clearInterv();}
    rightDelivered[0].onclick = function() {clearDeliv();}

    //await sleep(2000);

    if (active[0].innerText == "Active on Messenger") {
        chColorsForActive();
    }
    else if (received[0].title == "Delivered") {
        await chColorsForDelivered();
    }
}
//for delivered
async function chColorsForDelivered() {
    y = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        chColorsDelivered();
        await sleep(1000);
    }
}

function chColorsDelivered() {
    if (y === 1) {
        color = "#1e1e1e";
        y = 2;
    } else {
        color = "orange";
        y = 1;
    }

    rightDelivered[0].style.background = color;
}
//accessories
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

I put it into async. First I tried to

- await for the variable `received = await document.getElementsByClassName("_2her");` (it wasn't enough)
- then I tried to sleep for 2 seconds (it was working)
- tried to await the inner function (it was working too) But i have no idea why is it working if I wait for the **inner** function. I doesn't make sense to me. If I delete the `await chColorsForDelivered();` await here It's complaining about the title is undefiend.

*If you run this script in your messenger you will see an orange blinking span in the conversation information (where you see the pictures and stuffs, just delete the `if`)(It's only blinking if you have a Delivered message).*